# Opening jQuery Dialog with Post Data

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, ajax

I am trying to open a jQuery dialog programmatically. I am able to open the dialog but I am not able to send post data to the dialog.

Here is the code.

HTML:

```
<div data-role="page" id="rename-dialog">
        <?php
            $current_group = $_POST['gr_name'];
            $current_code = $_POST['gr_code'];
            $current_id = $_POST['in_id'];
        ?>

        <div data-role="header" data-theme="d" class="ui-header ui-bar-d" role="banner">
            <a href="#main-page" class="ui-btn-left ui-btn ui-shadow ui-btn-corner-all ui-btn-icon-notext ui-btn-up-d" data-icon="delete" data-iconpos="notext" data-corners="true" data-shadow="true" data-iconshadow="true" data-wrapperels="span" data-theme="d" title="Close" ktbt_p_pass="1">
                <span class="ui-btn-inner">
                    <span class="ui-icon ui-icon-delete ui-icon-shadow">&nbsp;</span>
                </span>
            </a>
            <h1 class="ui-title" role="heading" aria-level="1">Rename <?php echo $current_group; ?></h1>
        </div>

        <div data-role='content'>
            <form id='rename-group-form' action='' method='post'>
                New name for <?php echo $current_group; ?>: <input type='text' name='new-group-name'><br>
                <input id='rename-submit' type='submit' data-theme='b' value='Rename'></input>
            </form>
        </div>
</div>
```

JAVASCRIPT:

```
var g_code = parseInt($(this).attr("id"));
var i_id = parseInt($(this).attr("value"));
var g_name = $(this).attr("text");

$.mobile.changePage( "#rename-dialog", {transition: 'slideDown', role: 'dialog'}, {
        type: "post",
        data: {gr_code: 'test', in_id: 'test', gr_name: 'test'}
});
```

Basically this opens the dialog but I get an error that the indexes g_code, in_in and gr_name are undefined.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that all of the pertinent code is shown in your question ...

Since you have the code that gets the values for g_code, i_id, and g_name outside of any block , $(this) is not defined. For instance, in this case:

```
$("#item").click(function() {
    var item_id = $(this).attr("id");
});
```

$(this) would be a reference to the DOM element with an id of "item", because the selector was "#item".

It is likely that, if the code from you question is not inside of a selector block, that it needs to be moved into one, or that you need to replace 'this' with an actual selector to grab the DOM element you want.

If none of these answers apply, please post more of the code to give a better context of what's happening.

Comment: I changed the variables to constants but the same problem is occuring. See the edit in the code in the question.

Comment: Since you changed them to constants, for you to get that message means that those variables are used elsewhere. Check where else they are used.